# Laravel 5.1 - Custom validation language file

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5.1

Is it possible to conditionally set a custom language file (e.g. `resources/lang/en/validation_ajax.php`) for a validation request? Just to be clear, I don't want to change the app language, just use another set of messages depending on the request origin.

When I make an ajax validation call I want to use different messages since I'm showing the error messages below the field itself. So there's no need to show the field name (label) again.

I know you can define labels on `'attributes' => []` but it's not worth the effort since I have so many fields in several languages.

I'm using a FormRequest (there's no manual call on the Controller just a type hint).

Comment: You could use `trans()` in `'attributes' => []` and `'messages' => []`.

Comment: I don't get how's that practical. Laravel also automaticly generates the error array so I would need to change that for each case, so I could just do it directly on the attributes (and that's the whole problem since I have lots of fields). By using another file I can easily remove the :attributes and take care of the ~5% edge cases manually.

Comment: But if you require `resources/lang/en/validation_ajax.php` in a `ServiceProvider`, wont it be available for `trans()`?

Comment: using `trans()` means I need to reprocess the array (for each type of request/response) and that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the `messages()` method for a specific request (let's say login request). Let me show you: At first place, you need yo create a new custom Form Request, here we will define a custom message for `email.required` rule:

```
<?php namespace App\MyPackage\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class LoginRequest  extends Request {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'email.required' => 'how about the email?',
        ];
    }


    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed']
        ];
    }
}
```

> Only `email.required` rule message will be override. For password it will display the default message set at `validation.php` file.

Now, apply the form request at your controller function like a type hint:

```
class LoginController{

    public function validateCredentials(LoginRequest $request){
        // do tasks here if rules were success
    }
}
```

And that is all. The `messages()` method is useful if you need are creating custom packages and you want to add/edit validation messages.

### Update

If you need to carry the bag of messages on into your package's lang file then you can make the following changes:

1. At your package create your custom lang file:

   ```
   MyPackage/resources/lang/en/validation.php
   ```
2. Add the messages keeping the same array's structure as `project/resources/lang/en/validation.php` file:

   ```
   <?php
   return [
       'email' => [
           'required' => 'how about the email?',
           'email' => 'how about the email format?',
       ],
   ];
   ```
3. Finally, at your `messages()` method call the lang's line of your package respectively:

   ```
   public function messages(){
       return [
           'email.required' => trans('myPackage::validation.email.required'),
           'email.emial' => trans('myPackage::validation.email.valid'),
       ];
   }
   ```

Comment: I don't want to manually override the values, just load another file with all the definitions for all the ajax requests. Will I need to manually do something like `if ($request->ajax()) { // load another validation.php and return the array }` on every single Request/message()? Thanks!

Comment: Use your imagination. In messages() function I am returning an array. So, Just return the inclusion of a file containing all the definitions for ajax.

Comment: @manix, what if we need to add another validation message in messages method. One custom message for required email, another custom message for valid email? I know we can add custom array to achieve such thing in validation.php language file, but I don't want to make those globals.

Comment: @IrfanAhmed, I do not understand your question at all, but two things: 1. I have edited the example, might it can help you how to add more messages. 2. The messages in packages are not global because they area are only available when you load/call the package

Comment: @manix, I already tried the update you posted, I don't think if we can return multiple validation messages against single field i:e email.required and email.email. But we can add different elements like email.required, password.required and so on. Have you tried that? If there are multiple validations fail against email let say, it will only read the first custom message. Rest of the validation messages will be loaded from the default language file(resources/lang/en/validation.php)

Comment: @IrfanAhmed, Ohh, got it! Lets see: (1) `I don't think if we can return multiple validation messages against single field`: Yes, you can. Instead of call `$errors->first('email')` you can get all messages for an input with `$errors->get('email')`. (2) `If there are multiple validations fail against email let say, it will only read the first custom message`. Yes, but if you want display all messages from your custom lang file then you need to overwrite all the string from resources lang file. If you want, try to publish a new question, then tag me here and I could take a look.